# git mess -overwrite master with branch?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I got myself into a right tailspin this morning and had to create a branch to revert to my last commit in. Now the master branch is a mess and the only thing i'm interested in is this new branch with the revert. How can i force master to be the same as the reverted branch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git checkout yourbranch
git branch -f master yourbranch
git checkout master
```

If `yourbranch` is not a direct descendant of `master` this will require a forced update of the branch and might result in problems for other users who have cloned that repository (essentially it's history rewriting).

Comment: ok - so the branch was created using tortoisegit from the log i selected "create branch at this version"

Comment: does that mean it is a direct descendant?

Comment: No, it's not. If you haven't done any commits on the new branch, then it's exactly the other way round: `master` is a descendant of `yourbranch`. Since you are talking about "revert commit in a branch" I think your branches have diverged (use `gitk` to verify)

Comment: would i be better off deleting master, creating a new master by branching the new branch and naming it master?

Comment: No, it would have the same effect. Branchnames in git are just labels pointing to a commit. Each commit itself points to its parent(s)

Comment: so what would you say would be the best path?

Comment: That totally depends on the nature of the repository, the involved developers, project guidelines, your willingness to take rantings from other people, … If you don't care about rewriting history, simple force-push the branch. Otherwise you are pretty much left with your messed up history: revert all changes you don't need and live with it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3101/discussion-between-knittl-and-iwayneo)